# How to pass data to update Order tracking number in magento 2 using REST API?

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api, shipment-tracking

I am passing data to update tracking code :

```
$userData = [
    "entity" => [
            "paymentStatusId" => 10
            "orderStatusId" => 8
            "tracking_code" => "237948723894789234"
            "comment" => "Neuer Kommentar"
            "transactionId" => 0
        ]
    ]

$client->put('rest/V1/orders/46',$userData);
```

But it's returning below response. Please help me in passing the data for update tracking number or any order fields.

[image]

**Error:**

> [2017-01-13 09:48:32] main.CRITICAL: exception 'LogicException'
>   with message 'Property "PaymentStatusId" does not have corresponding
>   setter in class "Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface".' in
>   /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100
>       Stack trace:

Comment: U need to pass Billing & Shipping Address

Comment: But order is already placed  with a customer having billing and shipping address. Do you have any example ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ > **salesShipmentTrackRepositoryV1**

JSON:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "order_id": 345,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "entity_id": 1,
    "weight": 0,
    "qty": 0,
    "description": "Tracking code Descripton",
    "track_number": "1234567",
    "title": "Custom Tracking Code",
    "carrier_code": "custom"
  }
}
```

- Parent Id - `parent_id`: is the foreign key from `sales_shipment` table.
- Entity Id - `entity_id`(optional): is the entity id of `sales_shipment_track` table.
- Carrier Code: Custom (`custom`), DHL (`dhl`), Federal Express (`fedex`), etc..

You can take a look some tables: `sales_shipment`, `sales_shipment_track`.

**UPDATE SHIPMENT TRACK CODE:**

```
<?php

$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "test1234");
$ch = curl_init("http://mage21.loc/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);


$shiptrack = [
    "entity" => [
        "order_id"=> 347, //can find in `sales_shipment_track` and `sales_shipment`
        "parent_id" => 145, //can find in `sales_shipment_track` and `sales_shipment`
        "entity_id"=> 1, //can find in `sales_shipment_track`. Removing it if want to create a new shipment track.
        "weight"=> 0,
        "qty"=> 0,
        "description"=> "Tracking code Description",
        "track_number"=> "1234567",
        "title"=> "Custom Tracking Code",
        "carrier_code"=> "custom"
  ]
];



$ch = curl_init("http://magen21.loc/rest/V1/shipment/track");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($shiptrack));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

**CREATE NEW SHIPMENT TRACK**: If we want to **create the new shipment track, we need to remove `entity_id` param.**

Comment: I am getting error while updating after following your answer:
-------------------
[2017-01-16 06:41:57] main.CRITICAL: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`m2new`.`sales_shipment_track`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_SHIPMENT_TRACK_PARENT_ID_SALES_SHIPMENT_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sales_shipment` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)' in /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Comment: @BornCoder see my updated code.

Comment: i placed your code and run it. it is not showing any error and printing `$result` also but nothing is adding in `sales_shipment` table and `sales_shipment_track` table. How to check where data is inserting or updating?

Comment: You can open the order. Find in Shipment tab, open the shipment.

Comment: In shipment tab also , It's showing 'We couldn't find any records.'

Comment: Try to create the new one in Admin, and update this track.

Comment: i'm trying to update tracking from a csv file with 3 columns ( increment_id, carrier_code, tracking). Are "parent_id" "entity_id","weight""qty","description" required fields? or can i just post it like "$shiptrack = [
    "entity" => [
        "order_id"=> 10000012345,
        "track_number"=> "1234567",
        "title"=> "Federal Express",
        "carrier_code"=> "fedex"
  ]
];
"?